# How to make my app Not-uninstalable and Not-force-stoppable?

Tags: android

I want to make my application such that if somebody tries to force-stop he/she should not be able to do it.Like in Applock.apk.And I also want to know if there is any way to make my app such that no-body can uninstall it.

Comment: I would not want to have an application I cannot uninstall...

Comment: Not force stoppable? Wow! You want to act like an alien abducting a ship by force?

Comment: Like **Gallrey Lock** App.

Comment: There might be possibility of requirement. If it is possible to do so, we should provide solution for that instead of commenting what is right or wrong. Even Google don't allow user to uninstall its application still you are using it @returntrue.

Comment: I`m not using any Google applications.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, i agree. But whenever such application is developed, as i posted answer, it ask for permission. This permission is Administrator permission and without reading whole content, if user accept any thing, it is his fault. But the point is, such feature is available in Android and user can implement it. Even my application which i am developing for my client has this feature. So sometimes it is good thing to have this feature. There always be some pros and cons of any feature. :)

Comment: that´s true, that´s true... :)

Comment: yes I meant AppLock is also providing this feature so that if somebody tries to break the pattern lock he would not be able to do by force stopping the app and no body can uninstall applock.I am making some app which also need these requirements.So many downvotes :(

Comment: Chintan Rathore Please tell how would I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to have this feature.

What you need to do is Enable Administration rights in your application. There is a demo app in Android SDK samples.

Please check this **[Sample Application](https://github.com/prashantadesara/DeviceAdminDemo)** created by **prashantadesara**

[image]

[image]

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
</intent-filter>
```

> For more info and advance example you can check your android-sdk path (>= android-8).
>
> \samples\android-[>=8]\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\app\DeviceAdminSample.java

Comment: You can still stop the application with `adb shell am force-stop your.package.name`

Answer (score 0):

To make your app resurrect soon after it was `Force Closed`, Register an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` inside your application's `onCreate` Method just like this:

```
public void onCreate(){
Log.v("MyApplication", "onCreate triggered")
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
     public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex){
         Log.v("MyApplication", "onUncaughtException triggered. Error:")
         ex.printStackTrace()
         //restart your app here like this
         Intent i = new Intent(this, TheClassYouWannaStart.class);
         getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);
     }
});
}
```

P.S. Only `System` applications are uninstallable though they too can be uninstalled by a `root` user.